# Karate UI - Interaction with already opened browser

Tags: karate

We are trying to test a **POS(Point of sale)** web application run on chromium(hosted in docker container). Chromium is run in **kiosk mode** so you would not see address bar, menu bar etc. Now the tricky part for us is to interact with this web application which is already open and running. I am just wondering which route or method of **karate-ui** should I use in this case so that I don't end up opening a fresh browser session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to have Chrome start with the debug-port enabled: `--remote-debugging-port` - so if you can get the POS team to make this change, you are in business. It should be easy actually

a) pass an enviroment variable so the POS docker container adds that CLI arg to chrome

b) allow that port for the Docker container

You may get some ideas from the Karate Docker container: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-docker/karate-chrome/supervisord.conf

Then use the Karate UI driver config as `start: false, port: <port you set, typically 9222>`

Comment: Hi @Peter Thomas, thanks a lot for suggesting `start: false` parameter. I tested it with local chromium instance on a mac and it absolutely worked fine. But however, there is a little problem as the app/window is getting closed by karate at the end of test run. As its a POS application we would like it to run on the device forever(24/7).  We just want to poke the app and leave it as it is once the test is run. Is there any way for karate not to close the window? my argument for it is karate did not invoke the browser in the first place so it should not close it as well. Do you agree :) ?

Comment: @yek - yeah that makes complete sense. feel free to open an issue. you can even try contribute code, I can provide suggestions on GitHub for anyone who is interested. but - maybe the Java API is more suitable for this special case: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#chrome-java-api

Comment: I raised the issue
https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1352